# Segmentation fault in saving file pointer in a struct

Tags: c, file, gcc

I have a file pointer `current_file` of type `FILE *current_file;`. When I run this code

```
current_file = fopen ("file.text", "r");
struct buffer *buf;
buf->file = current_file;
```

I keep ending with a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. Here `buffer` is a struct like so:

```
struct buffer {
    FILE *file;
    int size;
};
```

I am completely stuck wit what's making this die. Thanks for taking time to read this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only declare buf to be a pointer of the type buffer, but there is no memory allocated for the struct.
Therefore you have an uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't initialized `buf` before using the deference operator in `buf->file = current_file;`